# Composer Update "man-in-the-middle attack" error

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, composer-php

I cloned one of my local project and executed `composer update` but I am getting some error:

> [Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]
>   The contents of
>   http://packagist.org/p/friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle$f1d8c88e21c3636c7d6d8d66f3e98ce2c83de942d1ab652f76e8c4f82e2c6363.js
>   on do not match its signature. This should indicate a
>   man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer again and report this
>   if you think it      is a mistake.

I also tried to clear composer cache but nothing is working.

Could someone give me an idea behind the issue so that it could be helpful for me.

Composer Version: b482ebe0ca18321d9322bd913af73c1c55adebf1

Comment: did you try `--prefer-dist` in the update?

Comment: See https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1431

Comment: For me my mistake was to : sudo **-u www-data** composer update

Answer (score 11):

In my scenario, adding the following lines to `composer.json` fixed the issue.

```
"repositories": {
  "packagist": { "url": "https://packagist.org", "type": "composer" }
}
```

#### Edit

If you have more then one repository:

```
  "repositories": [
      { "type": "composer", "url": "https://packagist.org" },
      { "type": "git", "url": "git@bitbucket.org:repo_name/proj_name.git" }
  ],
```

Comment: Where is that composer.json file I'm using ubantu 16.04 lts ?

Comment: @SagarGautam , If exist, it should be in your project root dir

Comment: Thank you for your response i'll see

Answer (score 4):

fix packagist repo as well with config option

```
composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Comment: The solution worked without editing any files. Just run this command in the terminal. I used it in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was to shut down my firewall included in FortiClient, after that, all worked. The Firewall seems to be the "man in the middle" ;)

Answer (score 2):

By adding below code in composer.json file

> "repositories": {
>    "packagist": { "url": "https://packagist.org", "type": "composer" }
>   }

For more info: http://tastytuts.net/php-tutorials/composer-update-man-middle-attack-error/

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when my internet connection was very unstable, that resulted in corrupted file. Do you have a "correct" connection ?

If your connection is right, try deleting your `composer.lock` file and removing everything what's in your `vendor/` directory then do `php composer.phar install`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Javad said, the `--prefer-dist` should work.

I have used this for the following problem:

```
[Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]
The contents of http://packagist.org/p/symfony/translation$452e624e2b8bf261
b553b79c0bfc170e5432455ebb33e9fbce585241a5fb7a16.json do not match its sign
ature. This should indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running compose
r again and report this if you think it is a mistake.
```

This code has worked for me:

```
composer update --prefer-dist
```

It timeouts for quite some time, sometimes up to 15 minutes, but then it starts downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me
Update composer.json file with following , you will find that in users\Name of the user\AppData\Roaming\Composer

```
{
    "repositories": {
        "packagist": {
            "url": "https://packagist.org",
            "type": "composer"
        }
    }
}
```