# Packagist isn't available

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I can't download a library with composer from packagist.
This is the error:

```
[Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]                                                                    
  The contents of https://packagist.org/p/provider-latest%240cbfb40ab72a881d21b70f78286d39cd72e3b0eb8704c13e79dc49624  
  e549973.json do not match its signature. This could indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer again  
   and report this if you think it is a mistake.
```

And the site of packagist is unvalaible.

[packagist](https://packagist.org)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer Update "man-in-the-middle attack" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977581/composer-update-man-in-the-middle-attack-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just wait until packagist will be back online. Based on this tweet: https://twitter.com/packagist/status/953257504565334016 it should not take that long.